# How to Customize Notification view in ios 6

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

*i m trying to customize notification view, like when we receive default notification its displaying 'DOT' symbol, but i want below image format, here i attached whatever i required notification in my app. pls help me any body knows,*

[image]

under didReceiveRemote Notification i wrote, like below

```
    mv1 = [[mv alloc]init];
    NSLog(@"test%@",userInfo);
    [mv1 displayItem:userInfo];  // custom method

   imgview.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"img1.jpeg"];
    //    NSMutableDictionary *test = [userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"];
//    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Message" message:[test objectForKey:@"alert"] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
//    [alert show];
     //[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"pushNotification" object:nil userInfo:userInfo];
```

Answer (score 1):

You cant customize notification centre. Because it is related with the OS not a part of your app. Apple wont allow this customization .